# How do I write a regular expression in Lua that is equivalent to /(\(\))?$/ in js

Tags: regex, lua

I want to write a regular expression that is equivalent to the following Javascript regexp:

`/^(\(\))?$/`
to match "()" and ""

I cannot find an equivalent representation in Lua. The problem I had was I could make multiple characters followed by "?".

For example,

`^%(%)$` can be used to match out "()"

`^%(%)?$` can be used to match out "(" and "()"

but `^(%(%))?$` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, the `?` modifier in Lua's pattern language applies only to a single character class.  Instead of using patterns/regexes for this, how about something simpler: `foo == '()' or foo == ''`?  Or is your real problem something more complex?  If it is, please tell us what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/#op-pow) (a pattern-matching library for Lua).

```
local lpeg = require "lpeg"

-- this pattern is equivalent to regex: /^(\(\))?$/
-- which matches an empty string or open-close parens
local p = lpeg.P("()") ^ -1 * -1

-- p:match() returns the index of the first character 
-- after the match (or nil if no match)
print( p:match("()") )
```